# making this $(this) work

Tags: jquery

Ok I have a very basic function which moves the background position of a div to give it a 'sheen' effect and a second one which shifts it back.

If I get the div by its ID that works fine.  But when I try to make the function a bit more universal by using 'this' - it breaks.

This works fine:

```
function runsheen() {
$('#sheen').animate({backgroundPosition: '-400px 0px'},1000);
}

function resetsheen() {
$('#sheen').css({backgroundPosition: '-0px 0px'});
}
```

But this does nothing

```
function runsheen() {
$(this).animate({backgroundPosition: '-400px 0px'},1000);}

function resetsheen() {
$(this).css({backgroundPosition: '-0px 0px'});}
```

Running it with the ID version means a new function for every button - rubbish.  If I use 'this' I can reuse the code over and over, right? Can anyone help me make this work?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `$(this)` in any given function, `this` is a reference to the object on which the function is being invoked.

The easier way (assuming you're doing this on hover) is to pass the functions directly to the [`.hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) event:

```
$('div').hover(
  function () {
    $(this).animate({backgroundPosition: '-400px 0px'},1000);
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).css({backgroundPosition: '-0px 0px'});
  }
);
```

Or, modify your functions to take an argument and pass in the div to apply the effect to:

```
function runsheen($div) {
  $div.animate({backgroundPosition: '-400px 0px'},1000);
}

function resetsheen($div) {
  $div.css({backgroundPosition: '-0px 0px'});
}

$('div').hover(
   function () { runsheen($(this)); },
   function () { resetsheen($(this)); }
});
```

Comment: In my opinion, if you're going to write a function that takes a jQuery object as its argument, you might as well write the function as a jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 0):

`this` has a different scope in your second context. `this` in your second context is referring to the `function` not `#sheen`

What you could do is define `this` to a different meaning outside the function.

```
var self = this;

function runsheen() {
$(self).animate({backgroundPosition: '-400px 0px'},1000);}

function resetsheen() {
$(self).css({backgroundPosition: '-0px 0px'});}
```

Comment: Your idea is correct but not sure whether self should be declared globally. It'll always return the document object.

Comment: You are correct.  I was assuming these functions sat inside a json class.  If not you are correct it would return the document which is probably what he is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Make it a jQuery plugin maybe?

```
$.fn.runsheen = function() {
  this.animate({backgroundPosition: '-400px 0px'}, 1000);
  return this;
});
```

(same with the other one)

Then you just say

```
$('#sheen').runsheen();
```

or if you're in an event handler:

```
$('#whatever').click(function() {
  $(this).runsheen();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of "this" changes with they way you call your functions. If you call these functions from the document.ready function, it'll give you a document object. If you call it from within another object it'll give you the instance of that object.

Read a bit about **Execution Context** in jQuery/JavaScript. Try this: http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/object-oriented_javascript3/

**I'd suggest you get this cleared up and not look for a shortcut becuase this is one of the key concepts in JavaScript/jQuery.** So don't look for a quick-fix on this one but try to understand what you want to do and what is happening.